Outer div bigger than inner span for 1 pixel
When I wrap a text inside span and place it inside div and give a background color for span and div a div become 1 pixels bigger than span at scale 100% (bottom rim). When I set the scale at 50% it's gone. When I set scale at 200% the top rim also appears.
So why is that and how to get rid of it?


<style>
  div {
    background-color: red;
  }
  
  span {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>





div is a block element which takes all width that it can get, as span is inline and it takes what it needs.

I don't see the red border at the bottom when using the given CSS and HTML; you must have some other css rule interfering. https://jsfiddle.net/spr1gvz0/

@DanielBeck I have not any other CSS styles, I attacked screenshot from JSFiddle

the red part is the "linebox" and the yellow part is the "content area". Read the duplicate to understand each one and what properties control each one

@TemaniAfif yes, but why line-box height is not equal to content area height as I have only one child element and line-height: normal (default value). And why when I set display: inline-block to the  everything become good?

read the duplicate, I am explaining everything there

span display is inline by default and its space totally relies on the inner content's font size (in your case, it's "Some text"). Therefore, it does not take any width and height settings.
The W3 document states for Inline, non-replaced elements

The 'height' property does not apply. The height of the content area should be based on the font, but this specification does not specify how. A UA may, e.g., use the em-box or the maximum ascender and descender of the font.

To fix it, you should add display: inline-block; onto span, mostly, to give that element the ability of width and height settings


<style>
  div {
    background-color: red;
  }
  
  span {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>



To understand inline and inline-block, you can read this article with examples.
Note that, different browsers and versions can have different behaviors for inline. If you want to make it consistent, you can consider using the style reset on the top level of styles
span {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

